# Intel Graphics Driver for Kubuntu 14.10?

Tags: graphics, resolution, kubuntu, intel-graphics

I am running Kubuntu 14.10 on my computer, which is an Asus laptop with an Intel graphics card (type below):

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
```

I have done some research on this, and found that Intel does not have official graphics drivers released for this version of Kubuntu. Has anyone found a way around this? Maybe an old driver that is still compatible? My screen is stuck at a resolution of 4:3 right now, when it is supposed to be 16:9, and it is really annoying.

Thanks in advance for any responses! If you need any more information (within reason), just let me know, and I'll try to get it to you!

Edit: I have already looked at 01.org. The graphics installer there does not support my distribution (14.10), or at least, that is what is says. My question was simply, does anyone know a way around this, or do I just have to wait for Intel to release a new graphics installer for Kubuntu 14.10?

Comment: try to use this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers): `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` then do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Find out which card you have with `sudo lshw -c video` and see

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Download the proper one. You should be able to install it with `sudo dpkg -i package.deb`, you'll need to restart your X server after doing it.

Additional details to find out your exact device
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system